# use Angular dateformat but not in pipe

Tags: angular, date, angular-i18n

I want to use the function formatDate wich is used by datePipe of Angular
the function is in:

> angular/packages/common/src/i18n/format_date.ts

when i try to import it:

`import {format_date} from '@angular/common/src/i18n/format_date'`
I get an error:

> Cannot find module "@angular/common/src/i18n/format_date"

Any Solution to use this functio (or any other function used on pipes) in a busines logic file (not pipe)

Comment: Although the question is slightly different, I think it still answers it. If you fell it doesn't, notify me so that I can re-open it.

Answer (score 1):

That should be `formatDate`

```
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';
```